# Stream/Play audio files on mobile browsers

Tags: browser, audio, mobile, audio-streaming

I am trying to create a mobile website and want to be able to play/stream audio files.I have tried html5's audio tag and tried testing it on opera mobile 10 simulator but it does not work. I have lots of audio files and the audio should be auto played.

---

sidenote:
Also, i need to test my website for android and iphone mobile phones. I am downloading android emulator for windows. I tried searching for iphone emulator for windows but there are none...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phone emulators aren't always a good indicator as they do not usually have a media player installed. The best way to test is to find someone with an actual Andriod / Blackberry / iPhone.

You should try the same HTML5 code with an actual phone. Note that Opera Mobile 10 does not have support for the video/audio tag. If you're interested in streaming to mobiles without HTML5, [you should check this FAQ entry for more information](http://login.netromedia.com/Solutions/View.aspx?ID=d71e515f-a48b-4720-8f9a-7953691edc44).